# How do I pass a scalar via a TensorFlow feed dictionary

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

My TensorFlow model uses `tf.random_uniform` to initialize a variable. I would like to specify the range when I begin training, so I created a placeholder for the initialization value.

```
init = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="init")
v = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((100, 300), -init, init), dtype=tf.float32)
initialize = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

I initialize variables at the start of training like so.

```
session.run(initialize, feed_dict={init: 0.5})
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("Embedding/random_uniform:0", dtype=float32)
```

I cannot figure out the correct `shape` parameter to pass to `tf.placeholder`. I would think for a scalar I should do `init = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=0, name="init")` but this gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Incompatible shapes for broadcasting: (100, 300) and (0,)
```

If I replace `init` with the literal value `0.5` in the call to `tf.random_uniform` it works.

How do I pass this scalar initial value via the feed dictionary?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Define `init` with a scalar shape as follows:

```
init = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(), name="init")
```

This looks like an unfortunate implementation detail of [`tf.random_uniform()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cc3153a7a0a23533d14ead34db37e4ccd7892079/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py#L188): it currently uses `tf.add()` and `tf.multiply()` to rescale the random value from [-1, +1] to [`minval`, `maxval`], but if the shape of `minval` or `maxval` is unknown, `tf.add()` and `tf.multiply()` can't infer the proper shapes, because there might be broadcasting involved.

By defining `init` with a known shape (where a scalar is `()` or `[]`, not `0`), TensorFlow can draw the proper inferences about the shape of the result of `tf.random_uniform()`, and your program should work as intended.

Comment: Can you and Eugene Brevdo make answering these questions your full-time jobs? :-)

Comment: One week out of seven, it is my full-time job - the other weeks I do it for fun! :-)

Comment: @mrry Can you please take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930725/tensorflow-pass-an-integer-to-graph . Thank you!

Comment: FYI: `tf.mul` has been changed to `tf.multiply`. See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a placeholder to pass the scalar since any tensor, sparsetensor or nexted tuple of tensor or sparsetensor can be ok. The [doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/aaaf1908758c2c1fadf534b6dccf6fdea1bdc18b/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L870) reads that:

> ```
> The optional `feed_dict` argument allows the caller to override
> the value of tensors in the graph. Each key in `feed_dict` can be
> one of the following types:
> * If the key is a `tf.Tensor`, the
>   value may be a Python scalar, string, list, or numpy ndarray
>   that can be converted to the same `dtype` as that
>   tensor. Additionally, if the key is a
>   `tf.placeholder`, the shape of
>   the value will be checked for compatibility with the placeholder.
> * If the key is a
>   `tf.SparseTensor`,
>   the value should be a
>   `tf.SparseTensorValue`.
> * If the key is a nested tuple of `Tensor`s or `SparseTensor`s, the value
>   should be a nested tuple with the same structure that maps to their
>   corresponding values as above.
> ```

And in your scenario, any tensor, like constant or variable or placeholder, can be appropriate.

```
init = tf.constant(0)
init_1 = tf.Variable(0)
v = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((100, 300), -init, init), dtype=tf.float32)
initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(intialize, feed_dict={init: 0.5})
sess.run(intialize, feed_dict={init_1: 0.5})
```

You can pass either float or int to it because only placeholder checks data type as stated above.