# tensorflow pass an integer to graph

Tags: tensorflow

I need to loop in graph for different times. I am unable to pass the integer variable through feed_dict.

```
rough1 = tf.Graph()
with rough1.as_default():
    st = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = ())
    d = tf.Variable(0)   
    for i in range(st):
        d = tf.add(d,1)

with tf.Session(graph = rough1) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    s = sess.run([d], feed_dict={st:3})
    print s
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build a Tensorflow graph, the graph isn't actually evaluated until you call `tf.Session.run`. A consequence of this is that Python constructs like `range` cannot inspect the value of a `Tensor` *except* by calling `run()`. Here, `range(st)` requires that the value of `st` be an integer known to Python, but the value of `st` is not known until the graph actually executes.

Put another way: the code that constructs the graph must not depend on the evaluation of that graph.

But here, you can just use a Python integer rather than a Tensor and everything works fine:

```
rough1 = tf.Graph()
with rough1.as_default():
  d = tf.Variable(0)   
for i in range(3):
    d = tf.add(d,1)

with tf.Session(graph = rough1) as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  s = sess.run([d])
  print s
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, I want that loop inside the graph to run different number of times every time i call the graph. Other variables should remain same as there are a lot of trained variables as well. Only this loop's count needs to be changed. I am not able to do that no matter what I try. :(

Comment: If you want variable numbers of iterations based on a Tensor's value, you probably want `tf.while_loop`. See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#while_loop  But note this is a somewhat unusual thing to do; it is usually used for things like RNN models that have variable lengths.

Comment: Yes, I am making RNN model. Although I could not find any code on internet where any variable length has been used. It would be great favor if you could provide me some link where this variable length looping has been used. Thank you :)

Comment: If you are building an RNN model, I would look at Tensorflow's `dynamic_rnn` support, which should handle many of the details for you. (The implementation of `dynamic_rnn` is based around while loops.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it is what you are looking for.

```
st=1
rough1 = tf.Graph()
with rough1.as_default():
  d = tf.Variable(0)   
for i in range(st):
    d = tf.add(d,1)

with tf.Session(graph = rough1) as sess:
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  s = sess.run([d])
  print s
```